# Struts ajax 404 error

Tags: java, jquery, ajax, jsp, struts2

structs.xml file

```
<package name="admin" extends="struts-default" namespace="/admin">
<!-- Add Login Functionality -->
<interceptors>

<interceptor class="AdminLoginController" name="loginStack"></interceptor>
<interceptor-stack name="loginStack">
    <interceptor-ref name="loginStack" />
</interceptor-stack>
</interceptors>
<action name="testing" class="BookingsController" method = "testing">
    <interceptor-ref name="loginStack"></interceptor-ref>
    <interceptor-ref name="defaultStack" />
    <result type="stream">
        <param name="contentType">text/html</param>
        <param name="inputName">inputStream</param>
    </result>
</action>
</package>
```

Register.jsp file

```
function test()
{
    $.ajax({
        type : "Get",
        url : "testing.action",
        success : function(response)
        {
            alert("Success");
        }
    });
}

<button class="button warning" onclick="test()"  id="testApp">Testing</button>
```

BookingsContoller.java file

```
public String testing()
{
    try
    {
        return "SUCCESS";
    }
    catch(Exception e)
    {   
         return "error";
    } 
}
```

I am new to web development. I am trying to do a ajax call from jsp. But I am getting 404 not found error. I have added the my code snippets for reference. Please help me. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

you need to understand your config file first ,

```
<result type="stream">
        <param name="contentType">text/html</param>
        <param name="inputName">inputStream</param>
    </result>
```

means the response is expecting a "text/html" type response and the parameter inputName has a stream variable by name "inputStream" with getters and setters  , that inputStream is what you should be sending in response .

create a variable by name "inputStream" of data type say InputStream with getters and setters and then return SUCCESS .

in ajax , put an error field , like this :

```
$.ajax({
         type   :  "POST",
         url    :  "action",
         data   :  Data,
         encode :  true,
         error  :  function(){
             what should happen on error , if ajax call itself failed to specified url.
         }
      }).done(function(status){ 
         what should happen after successful response
        })
```